# i want to put user input and store it in an array when user types Exit, it should print the names the user typed in, ascending.. any tips?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, input

So here is my code. i´ve not managed to use the ascending.. i want the user to type infinite amount of names and then type exit to get the result..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter some Names");
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                names.add(scanner.next());
            } else {
                String s1 = scanner.next();
                if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(s1)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        String string = "the Names you wrote are : ";
        for (String x : names) {
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: You will never enter the `else` part. Since you're checking `scanner.hasNextLine` in the while loop itself, the check in the if statement is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(scanner.hasNextLine())` will never enter the `else` block because `scanner.hasNextLine()` will never be `false`.

Instead, do something like this:

```
String input = scanner.next();

if("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
    break;
} else {
    names.add(input);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's technically _necessary_ here, but it's good practice to compare with `"literal".equalsIgnoreCase(variable)` just in case the variable is `null`.

Comment: @jirassimok I think it's more readable the other way around, but you're right - it does make sense.